# What is the best way to get a substring of Select-String output?

Tags: string, file, powershell, parsing, powershell-2.0

I am running `Select-String` on a file which contains the following line:

```
....
Association ID: uj8da-21
....
```

`Select-String -Path "..path.." -Pattern "Association ID:" -SimpleMatch` gives me the file, the line number, the words "Association ID:", etc. All I want is the value. What's the best way to do this from the `Select-String` command?

And what if I wanted to extract a series of lines *after* this line (say, 10 additional lines) -- would the `-Context` argument be the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use match groups.

```
$matchInfo = Select-String -Path "C:\temp\text.txt" -Pattern "Association ID: (.*)" 
$matchInfo.Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

Context is the way to go.

```
$matchInfo = Select-String -Path "C:\temp\text.txt" -Pattern "Association ID: (.*)" -Context 0,10
$matchInfo.Matches.Groups[1].Value
$matchInfo.Context.PostContext
```